# Show that $(0,1)$ is a substructure of $(0,1]$ in the language $L=\{<\}$ but is not an elementary substructure of it in the same language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Show that the ordered set $(0,1)$ is a substructure of $(0,1]$ in the language $L=\{<\}$ but is not an elementary substructure of it in the same language.

Since the ordered set $(0,1)$ is a subset of the ordered set $(0,1]$ , it's also a substructure of it.

Now, $\varphi: (\exists x)(x=1)$ is satisfied in $(0,1]$ but not in $(0,1)$ so, $(0,1)$ is not an elementary substructure of  $(0,1]$.

So, I wonder if saying "the ordered set $(0,1)$ is a subset of the ordered set $(0,1]$" is enough to prove that $(0,1)$ is a  substructure of  $(0,1]$.

Comment: $\exists x (x=1)$ doesn’t work since the sentence needs to only have parameters in the substructure. (Otherwise nothing would be an elementary substructure of anything ever.) Replace with “there is a greatest element.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As spaceisdarkgreen points out, what you've done **isn't** correct: the language $L$ of pure linear order doesn't have a symbol for $1$, so "$\exists x(x=1)$" **is not** a sentence in the relevant language.

What you'll need to do is somehow *define* $1$ in the language of linear order alone; do you see a special property which $1$ has, in the structure $(0,1]$?

---

It's worth pointing out a subtlety of the notion of substructure: *as long as* our language has only relation symbols, then any sub*set* of our structure is (or rather, is the underlying set of) a substructure, but this is no longer true if our language includes function symbols - e.g. $\{$odd numbers$\}$ is not (the underlying set of) a substructure of $(\mathbb{N}; +)$, since it's not closed under $+$. In fact, even constant symbols (= zero-ary functions) kill this, since a subset not containing the thing named by a given constant symbol won't be a substructure.

It's also worth noting that you've in fact shown that $(0,1)$ is not even *elementarily equivalent to* $(0,1]$, and that this is actually a *stronger* property than not being an elementary substructure: e.g. $(0,{1\over 2}]$ is elementarily equivalent (in fact, isomorphic) to $(0,1]$, but is not an elementary substructure of it (why not?).

Comment: I think you misread their argument for the elementary substructure part.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Oh derp, quite right! Fixed.

Comment: I understood the part about substructure notion, but I can't come with an answer when you say "define 1 in the language of linear order alone" @NoahSchweber

Comment: @LeylaAlkan Do you see something about $1$, in the context of the linear order $(0,1]$, which makes it particularly "special" in any way (besides just having a fancy name)?